# Describing blocks of a matrix using Jordan Canonical Form

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $8 \times 8$ matrix over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ such that

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
   A_{1} & A_{2}\\\
A_{3} & A_{4}
 \end{pmatrix}$$
where each blocks $A_i$ are $4 \times 4$.

I am working on a problem involving $A$, and I found out that the Jordan Canonical Form of $A$ is $J_3(0) \oplus J_3(0) \oplus J_2(0).$ Is it possible to describe the blocks $A_i$ for each $i$ using the Jordan Canonical Form of $A$? The goal is to say something about the sum $A_4A_3A_2+ A_3A_2A_4$. I think this is always equal to the zero matrix, but cannot prove it. I've tried plugging in some values for $P$ and I always get the zero matrix, but of course this is not a proof, as I have to try it for all invertible $8 \times 8$ matrices over $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Here's what I tried:

The Jordan Canonical Form of $A$is $J_3(0) \oplus J_3(0) \oplus J_2(0)$ implies that $A$ is similar to $J_3(0) \oplus J_3(0) \oplus J_2(0)$, that is, $$PAP^{-1}= J_3(0) \oplus J_3(0) \oplus J_2(0)= 
 \left(\begin{array}{@{}cccc|cccc@{}}
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{array}\right)
$$
for some invertible $8 \times 8$ matrix $P$ over $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

I tried to write $P$ as
$$P=\begin{pmatrix}
   P_{1} & P_{2}\\\
P_{3} & P_{4}
 \end{pmatrix}$$
where each blocks $P_i$ are $4 \times 4$, but $P^{-1}$ becomes really complicated this way.

I cannot really think of a method because $P^{-1}$ becomes complicated especially for this large arbitrary matrices.

Please help. Thank you so much.

Comment: This is a very nice observation? If I may ask, how did you stumble upon it? It's not everyday that I'm observing that particular Jordan form and the odd square-block relation! I had an idea which I quickly debunked, but basically we could try to prove that if $A_2A_3A_4 + A_4A_3A_2 = 0$ then $EAE^{-1}$ has the same property for $E$ an elementary matrix (row addition, row switching and row multiplying matrices). While this is an arduous task as well, there are certainly fewer cases to check, and since every invertible matrix is a product of elementary matrices, we'd be done by induction?

Comment: Hello Teresa! This actually came a long way from a problem that I was trying to solve. Actually, I found out that $A$ has other two possible JCF aside from the one in the question, but they also have that property that the $A_3$ block is zero. It would be actually nice if I can prove what you said, because the conclusion will also work for the other possible JCFs as well! Thanks for this, I’ll try to work on it.

Comment: Great. +1 and I hope you find some success!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Hello! Unfortunately, my claim is actually false since I found a counterexample where the sum is not the zero matrix. But I’m still hopeful since what I really want to prove is that the sum is never equal to the identity matrix. Thank you for giving me the idea about elementary matrices :)

Comment: I see! Proving that it does not equal the identity matrix , well that might evoke a simper proof because the constraints are very heavy. Let me see if I can think of something there. I'm happy that I could be of help, though!